# How to design a Navigation-Based app for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am a new iPhone developer learning Objective-C, and trying to build an iPhone app using a Navigation-Based template.  The way I want this application to function is to have a button, which takes the user to the second screen after being pressed.  Unfortunately, I have not seen any examples of this online, and am unsure how to do this.

I realize that I won't be using a table view, where I would select a particular row that would then take me to another screen.  What view would be appropriate to have a button, and possibly a search bar on the first screen, which would then allow me to navigate over to a second screen?  I would need the second screen to have a table view which would hold a list of rows retrieved from a sqlite database.  What method in the RootViewController (i.e. the first screen) would I use to place the code to execute when the button is selected (i.e. fires an event)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand you question correctly, but...

In RootViewController:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithStyle:...];
  [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [[self view] addSubview:button];
}

- (void) onButtonPressed
{
  SecondViewController* controller = ...;
  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

The `addTarget:action:forControlEvent:` selector registers the 'callback' that should be called every time the button is pressed. In the callback (`onButtonPressed`) you just create new controller and push it into the navigation controller.

Usually you should do it in the Interface Builder. Just add `IBAction` and connect it to the event.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply, your solution worked!  Take care.